# Automatically inherit an imported video's encoding

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I use the Visual Sequence Editor to compile highlights from my aerial drone. After editing the source(s), I want the exported video to have the same dimensions, fps, encoding, and quality as the original(s).  I manually set these at the moment, then save them in a preset for future use.  However sometimes I forget what camera I have used that day and load the wrong preset, this isn't a big problem but it is a waste of time to render the sequence again.

Is there a way to automatically set the output parameters to mimic the source video in Blender?

Comment: you should sign up for the following mailing list if no answer is forth coming.  That's a really useful tool to have.  http://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-funboard

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do this. However you would be able to do this via python.

I dont think the ffmpeg libraries (which is what blender uses to read and write video and audio files) have python bindings included with blender.

To write a python script to do this, you will need to use another python library, such as [pipeffmpeg](http://ttps://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipeffmpeg/)